# Поиск нескольких имен в цикле

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Что есть**
Набор данных в виде: `Тема пиьма – Имя / комментарий`, наборов может быть несколько, выполняется split по \n

**Как работает**
 1. Разбиваем строки при помощи split на отдельные массивы
 2. Запускаем цикл по количеству строк, в котором:
 3. При помощи .split(' – ') отделяем темы письма от имен и комментариев
 4. При помощи .split(' / ') отделяем имена и комментарии
 5. При совпадении имени, заменяем его на нужное нам и выполняем функцию addTask(name)
 6. Выводим итоговое сообщение с замененными именами в массив messageArr

**Кусок нынешнего кода**

```
var splittedMessage = result.messages.split('\n')
var messageArr = []
for (let i = 0; i<splittedMessage.length; i++) {
    let singleMessage = splittedMessage[i].split(' – ')
    let comment = singleMessage[1].split(' / ')
    let userName = comment[0]
    let description = comment.length > 1 ? comment[1] : ''
    if (comment[0] == 'Артем') {
        var name = '@username'
        addTask(name)
    } else if (comment[0] == 'Марк') {
        var name = '@username'
        addTask(name)
    } else {
        var name = 'Бот не понял, кто это такой. Кто-то не следует инструкции'
    }
    messageArr.push(`<b>${singleMessage[0]}</b> – ${name} ${description.length > 0 ? '/ '+ description : ''}`)            
}
```

**Что нужно** Код сейчас работает и выполняет свою функцию, но нет возможности проверить сразу несколько имен, которые писались бы в виде: `Тема пиьма – Имя, Имя, Имя, Имя / комментарий`

Помогите, пожалуйста, в реализации подобного сценария, либо советом, в какую сторону копать. К сожалению, текущих знаний не совсем хватает на корректную реализацию.

Answer (score 0):

```
let userNames = comment[0].split(",").map(i => i.trim());
let description = comment.length > 1 ? comment[1] : ''
if (userNames.indexOf('Артем') != -1) {
  ...
```